# Sharepoint Search Error: The SharePoint server was moved to a different location, custom login page

Tags: sharepoint, search

i am new on forums (so be nice if i am doing things the wrong way), i hope you guys help me solve this issue; i have spent 4 hrs, trying to get this work.
 i am trying to crawl my site collection content, but it’s not possible:

My farm is build this way

- SharePoint 2010 standard
- FBA and ntlm, anonymous access
- 2 WFE's, hardware balancing.
- Http to Https redirect using url Rewrite Module
- Custom FBA Login Page,
- Search account has full reading permission, on my app.
- in the default zone i have the server name, and in the crawl definition i have

I have a Test environment on my client's place with this configuration:

- SharePoint 2010 standard

  - FBA and ntlm, anonymous access
  - 1 WFE
  - Http to Https redirect using url Rewrite Module
  - Custom FBA Login Page,
  - Search account have full reading permission, on my app.
    on this environment SharePoint search works perfect.

when i try to  crawl my content source, i get the following  error

***SharePoint Search Error: The SharePoint server was moved to a different location, custom login page. ***
when i look the log file, there are 2 top level errors, and one delete.

Searching  this issue, i have found this:
-create a rule, excluding layouts Folder (tested, but its not working)
-write on server host file, the mapped URL, passing thru balancing device (not tested)
-Extending my web app and use only - NTLM authentication (not tested on my client environment, but i want this to be my last option)

Any ideas,
TX on advance

Comment: Did you find any fix for this? Seems like it has to do with the custom login page... Is extending the web application the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the http->https module is causing the issue. Try and configure production so you can access the url via https directly.

This will either confirm or rule out that it is the http module.

Comment: Nat,tx for your time,i will try that tomorrow and discard rewriter module in production and i will, let you know,  thanks again